# Adjusting Height of UIViews inside UITableViewCell after it is created not working

Tags: uitableview

I have some dynamic text content that should grow the cell vertically and I am doing it by calculating the height and returning that for the table cell. The table cell grows in size fine but the issue is growing the UIView inside the cell.

I set the height of the UIView inside the cell using the same method of calculating height using the following code but the UIView does not grow even after setting its frame. So below the businessDescriptionTextView is a Label and container is a UIView inside the cell. I am setting both of them and the getHeightBusinessDescription does return the correct height but for some reason it does not redraw

```
    cell.businessDescriptionTextView.text = self.dealLocation.company.description;
    cell.businessDescriptionTextView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.businessDescriptionTextView.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.businessDescriptionTextView sizeToFit];

    CGRect frame = cell.container.layer.frame;
    frame.size.height = [self getHeightBusinessDescription] + 50;
    cell.container.layer.frame = frame;
```

I have tried setNeedsDisplay on cell.container cell.businessDescriptionTextView and still no luck. I also tried the table reload

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

With the beginUpdates and endUpdates right after I set the frame size and still nothing happened.

Comment: Are you implementing the UITableViewDelegate method `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`?

Comment: is the UIView setup programatically or through a nib/storyboard?

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose: UIView is in a NIB and has a fixed size. I suspect it is caching and it reload the next time I go up and down to that same cell.

Comment: @NicholasHart: I am implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath and the height of the cell is good but the height of the subviews does not grow even if I set the frame size to increase for subview items.

Comment: Is the container property linked up to the uiview in the nib file?

Comment: Yes the container property is linked. I checked with the lldb and made sure it is not nil. It has a frame and the frame is updated after I do cell.container.layer.frame = frame; but the UI does not redraw until you get to that cell again.